# Botbuilder Dialogues dont support debounce or separate loops

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

How to achieve the following?
There are two types of listeners in botframework
one to the root dialog / where luis handler is attached to.
another is Prompts where an input from user is sought.

In both occassions. it is possible that user enters the inputs in a series of utterances and not necessarily only one.

how can Prompts in botbuilder collect in debounce pattern, esp when in middle of seeking inputs from user? and how can these be directed to luis while in middle of dialog?

e.g.
1.

```
bot: please enter your name
user: 1 sec
user: ok, it is Smith.
```

2.

```
bot: fetching the details from server... ( 5 sec pause makes user lose patience)
user: u there?
// This should not break the current dialog ( i.e. dialogue handler is preparing a response).
bot: yes, I am there.still waiting for a response from server. pls hold on. (after few secs...)
bot: got the details. here you go..
```

3. third example.

   bot: what was your experience?

   user: well, where shall I begin?

   user: it was kind of ok, but...

   user: not very good..

   user: but would recommend

the prompts should be able to collect these before reacting to each input...

Comment: Im about to try to do this on my bot, will post back if Im successful

Answer (score 0):

Here is what Im doing: using the library "debounce-queue" Im queueing the user messages in the bot.use({receive}) middleware. When the array of events get debounced, I proceed to merge the events (text, attachments, etc). After thats done I proceed to execute the next() middleware callback. Here is some code (also using lodash _), you might need to adapt to yours:

```
var debounces = {};
bot.use({
  receive: (event, next) => {
    if (event.type === 'message') {
      if (!debounces[event.address.user.id]) {
        debounces[event.address.user.id] = debounce(events => {
            var last = events[events.length-1];
            var event = last.event;
            _.reverse(events.splice(0, events.length - 1)).forEach(debounced => {
              event.text = debounced.event.text + ' ' + event.text;
              event.attachments = _.concat(event.attachments, debounced.event.attachments);
            })
            last.next()
          })
        }, 2000)
      }
      debounces[event.address.user.id]({ event, next });
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
})
```